# Allow max one of each special char with one exception for single quotes

Tags: regex

I was wondering if it is possible to simplify the following regular expression

```
^(?!.*([,\._\- ]).*\1)(?!.*[',\._\- ]{2})(?!.*(['])(?:.*\2){2})[',\._\- \p{L}]+$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CPliJi/1)

### Constraints

1. All of these characters can appear a maximum of one time each: `_-.`

   - The last character is a white space.
2. This character can appear a maximum of two times each: `'`
3. All special characters here can not appear consecutively.

### Details

1. `(?!.*([,\._\- ]).*\1)` - There cannot be 2 or more occurrences of any one character in `_-.`
2. `(?!.*[',\._\- ]{2})` - No char in the special char group can appear consecutively.
3. `(?!.*(['])(?:.*\2){2})` - Single quote special char cannot appear 3 or more times.

Comment: It would help if you posted sample data and which parts of it should match.

Comment: @dc-ddfe I did - in the regex demo link. What I have now is working but I imagine it can be simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write the pattern using a single capture group in combination with [negated character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) making use of [contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast)

You don' have to create a capture group `(['])` with a backreference `\2` to repeat a single quote 3 times, but you can just repeat that char 3 times.

As there do not seem to be `'` at the start or at the end, you can use a repeating pattern `\p{L}+(?:[',._ -]\p{L}+)*` to not have consecutive chars that you don't want.

Note that you don't have to escape the `'` and `_` in the character class, and you can move the `-` to the end so that you don't have to escape it.

```
^(?![^,._ \n-]*([,._ -]).*\1)(?!(?:[^'\n]*'){3})\p{L}+(?:[',._ -]\p{L}+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?![^,._ \n-]*([,._ -]).*\1)` Assert not 2 of the same chars `[,._ -]`
- `(?!(?:[^'\n]*'){3})` Assert not 3 times `'`
- `\p{L}+` Match 1+ times any kind of letter
- `(?:[',._ -]\p{L}+)*` Optionally repeat one of `[',._ -]` and again 1+ times any kind of letter
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cUPvGc/1)